# Mint: Executable: Command not Found

Tags: linux-mint

Let me preface this by mentioning that I am a total Linux newbie. I built a linux machine a few months ago that hosts a few applications and game servers and everything was working fine. I had to reboot the machine a few days ago and now one of the game servers that used to work great is no longer starting.
It basically says that the executable does not exist, even thought I can see it.

```
steam@Rochallor:~/sandstorm/Insurgency/Binaries/Linux$ ls
InsurgencyServer-Linux-Shipping  steam_appid.txt  steamclient.so
steam@Rochallor:~/sandstorm/Insurgency/Binaries/Linux$ file InsurgencyServer-Linux-Shipping
InsurgencyServer-Linux-Shipping: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, for GNU/Linux 3.4.1, BuildID[xxHash]=116f503e920192b9, stripped
steam@Rochallor:~/sandstorm/Insurgency/Binaries/Linux$ InsurgencyServer-Linux-Shipping
InsurgencyServer-Linux-Shipping: command not found
```

I read somewhere that I need to have the correct interpreter and indeed cannot see /lib64/l but I have no clue what to do about it (if it’s even an issue)

```
steam@Rochallor:/lib64$ ls
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  ld-lsb-x86-64.so.2  ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3
```

I also thought it might be a permission issue so I’ve tried a carpet bomb: sudo chmod a+rwx /home/steam/sandstorm/Insurgency/Binaries/Linux but without success.

I’m sure this has been discussed in another thread but I’ve been searching and trying stuff all morning and couldn’t find anything that worked for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Well it was was that easy. Adding the ./ worked out great when directly in the directory, I should have figured that out myself. I'll read a bit more on PATH because I still can't launch the executable from outside the directory, last time I tried playing with PATH I broke more thing than I fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a directory that contains `InsurgencyServer-Linux-Shipping` to your $PATH if you want to run it simply as `InsurgencyServer-Linux-Shipping`. If you are in the directory that contains `InsurgencyServer-Linux-Shipping` you can do:

```
PATH="$PWD":"$PATH"
```

You can now change to any other directory, for example run `cd` without an argument to change to your $HOME and run `InsurgencyServer-Linux-Shipping`. As long as the directory that contains the executable you want to start is not added to your $PATH you have to provide a full path to the directory before the executable name, for example `./InsurgencyServer-Linux-Shipping` if you are in the directory that contains the executable.

Comment: Both using ./ when directly in the folder and adding the folder to the PATH variable and the calling it from anywhere worked out great. Thanks!